# PIL SANE interface: where can I find it?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-scanner, twain, sane

Apparently PIL includes a SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy) interface - I'm looking at code right now that does

```
import sane
```

where sane is provided by PIL.

I've installed PIL under both OS X and Windows, but "import sane" doesn't work for me. I did a fair bit of googling to see if there's something extra I need to install but I'm not finding anything.

How do I get the SANE interface for PIL?

I'm happy with any SANE interface (doesn't have to be PIL), so if you know of an alternative that would help too.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** I never used SANE.

I don't think that sane is provided with the PIL library.

It seems, instead, that the package you're looking for is called [**pysane**](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysane/2.0.1).

Comment: Thanks Rik. Looks like pysane has been replaced by imagescanner, which I'm in the process of trying now.

Comment: @Parand: You're welcome! I'm glad to have been of some help :)